# can i integrate Paypal in iphone app for selling tickets

Tags: iphone, xcode, paypal, ios7

I am making app, in which i will sell tickets through the iPhone app,i have heard that apple might reject the app as they support in app purchase.So please anyone guide me in this regard as i don't want to use in app purchase to sell  tickets through iPhone app. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 supported categories of In-App Purchase items that you may sell:

> • Content
>
> • Functionality
>
> • Services
>
> • Subscriptions

It means you can not sell physical good via in app purchase **but yes you can use payment gateways to sell physical goods like PayPal, Stripe etc.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can integrate **Paypal** or **Stripe**. Please refer following links :

1. [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/)
2. [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios)